# Capacitive load - Circuit protection

Tags: amplifier, protection, current-limiting

I have a circuit which drives capacitve loads (they vary from around 800pf to 1600pf) and because of circumanstances like air polution and dust it can come to electrical contact to the surroundings or even short circuits.

The circuit uses a [MP104](https://www.apexanalog.com/resources/appnotes/an25u.pdf) to drive the load and when something happens, this is the part which is destroyed.

The output is driving 150V with a 50V/µs slew rate for falling and rising and holds the voltage for about 1µs. Between 2 Pulses there is a minimum of 1 µs pause. The Input of the amplifier is controlled by a DAC to control slew rate and so on.
[image: Apex MP104 cutout]

Where +VS is 150V and -VS the 0V potential for +VS.

I am searching for a circuit protection.

Conventional fuses are too slow for the driver. 
Currently I am exploring OCP possibilities like using a [LMG3411](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmg3411r070.pdf) to control +VS of the driver. It can even be a replacement for the MP104.

I can't tell the exact circumstances where the driver breaks because I just get feedback when it's too late. Also I am able to destroy the driver by making a short as load but wasn't able to determine an exact current where it breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Safe Operating Area curve does not tolerate arcing.

Using that plot Figure 16, at 150 volts from the plot, less than ONE AMP is allowed.

You may need to insert series current limiting resistance: non-inductive.

Different power transistors have different ability to tolerate pulse-energy overloads. NASA and the automotive manufacturers uncovered this, for oldstyle versus newstyle MOSFETS, about 20 years ago; the oldstyle MOSFETs were much more robust.

==========================================================

Can we do better? Can we detect the high current, and shut off the input? Yes.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGp9F1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you wish to use this circuit, I suggest you simulate it to ensure the pulse (short circuit detection) will propagate thru the 3 transistors quickly (10 or 20 nanoseconds). The 100pF caps may be needed.

To first test at 50 volts and 75 volts and 100 volts and 125 volts, reduce the resistor values of R13,14,15,16 proportionately; thus at 50 volts, make the resistors 1/3 of what I've suggested.

Comment: So basically in the case of a short circuit I set the control circuit active which pulls the output of the DAC over 1kOhm against ground?
I have as additional delay to the RC the td and tr of Q1+Q5 [150ns so no time in this case]?
You said that the industrie already made effort for such scenarios, can you link some resources to this?

Comment: the circuit continually monitors the current thru R1; when a short-circuit occurs, the voltage across R1 starts to rise and turns on Q1; about 20 nanoseconds later, delayed thru the 3 common-base high-voltage-sharing transistors, the voltage across R8 and diode D1 start to rise and charge C2 and begin to turn on Q5. NO ----- you cannot change what is inside the OpAmp; this circuit using R1 is trying to be rather fast, pulling the opamp input toward ZERO and having the opamp TRY to protect its transistors.

Comment: What if I remove R3-6 and Q2-4?